# Prefill a nested element with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms

Is it possible to pre-fill a `simple_fields_for` input with datas from another object ?

I have a `User` object. `User` has_one `Backpack`, `Backpack` has many `Pockets`, and `Pocket` has_many `Items`

When building my form, i'm using

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :backpack do |backpack| %>
      <%= render 'backpack', f:backpack %>
    <% end %>
```

Now, when I'm on `users#new`, the whole form is empty. I would like to initialize the `Backpack` fields with datas from another `Backpack` object, is it possible ? I tried by doing this:

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :backpack, @backpack do |backpack| %>
      <%= render 'backpack', f:backpack %>
    <% end %>
```

along with this in my `UsersController`:

```
@user = User.new
@backpack = Backpack.find(1).deep_clone include: [ :pockets, { pockets: :items } ]
```

But this doesn't work: for some reason, the `Backpack` fields are filled, but his `Pockets` and their `Items` are empty. I tried pretty much everything that came to my mind: checked my routes for nested objects, tried with and without deep_cloning, still, nested objects are nowhere to be found, which makes me wonder, is it even possible to initialize a form with prefilled nested models?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so for some reason, when I put a

```
<% @backpack.pockets.each do |pocket| %>
    <%= pocket.title %>
<% end %>
```

It displays all of the pockets titles, which means that I successfully cloned the backpack, BUT, using this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :pockets, @backpack.pockets do |pocket| %>
  <%= render 'pocket', f: pocket %>
<% end %>
```

Nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, it appears that the clone is not saved, therefore, using it to prefill the `simple_fields_for` will only results in prefilling the direct attributes, and none of the nested models, therefore, you'll have to save the clone, remove its attributes from the requestion params, and create it separately

```
@backpack = Backpack.find(1).deep_clone include: [ :pockets, { pockets: :items } ]
@backpack.save
```

and then, in the `Users#create` method

```
@user = User.new(user_params.except(:backpack_attributes))
@backpack = Backpack.new(params[:user][:backpack])
@backpack.save
@user.backpack = @backpack
```

This way, you'll have your new user, and your form will be prefilled with the backpack attributes and nested attributes.